# makefile run execute one time for all rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have write  a makefile that prepare  some files. I create ORIGINAL directory and then I use the file inside the folder for start the others rules

```
RDIR=.
RFILES:=$(wildcard $(RDIR)/*.vcf)
OUTDIR=ORIGINAL
OUTFILES=$(patsubst %.vcf,$(OUTDIR)/%.gz,$(RFILES))
BCFTOOLS=bcftools 
OUTSOMATIC=SOMATIC
OUTVARDICT=$(patsubst 
$(OUTDIR)/%vardict.gz,$(OUTSOMATIC)/%.somatic.vcf,$(wildcard 
$(OUTDIR)/*vardict.gz))
OUTMUTEC2=$(patsubst 
$(OUTDIR)/%mutect2_all.gz,$(OUTSOMATIC)/%mutect2.somatic.vcf,$(wildcard 
$(OUTDIR)/*mutect2_all.gz))

OUTVARSCAN2=$(patsubst 
$(OUTDIR)/%varscan.gz,$(OUTSOMATIC)/%varscan2.somatic.vcf,$(wildcard 
$(OUTDIR)/*varscan.gz))

.PHONY: all

all: $(OUTDIR) $(OUTFILES) $(OUTSOMATIC) $(OUTVARDICT) $(OUTMUTEC2) 
$(OUTVARSCAN2)


$(OUTDIR)/%.gz: %.vcf
    bgzip -c $<  > $@


$(OUTDIR):
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@

$(OUTSOMATIC):
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@



$(OUTSOMATIC)/%.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%vardict.gz
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS -i 'INFO/STATUS ~ ".*Somatic"' $<  > $@



$(OUTSOMATIC)/%mutect2.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%mutect2_all.gz
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS $<  > $@



$(OUTSOMATIC)/%varscan2.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%varscan.gz
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS -i 'SS="2"' $<  > $@




clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTDIR)
    rm -rf $(OUTSOMATIC)
```

I need to launch 3 time make -f Makefile for execute all the rules. How 
can improve that script?

What is the right way?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your makefile is zip vcf files in one directory into gz files in a second directory, then use those gz files to build vcf files in a third directory (building the directories as needed), and that those final vcf files are the real goal.

You can do it in one pass, if you modify the variable assignments to derive target names from the planned gz files, not the gz files that already exist:

```
OUTVARDICT=$(patsubst $(OUTDIR)/%vardict.gz,$(OUTSOMATIC)/%.somatic.vcf,$(filter $(OUTDIR)/%vardict.gz, $(OUTFILES)))

OUTMUTEC2= $(patsubst $(OUTDIR)/%mutect2_all.gz, $(OUTSOMATIC)/%mutect2.somatic.vcf, $(filter $(OUTDIR)/%mutect2_all.gz, $(OUTFILES)))

OUTVARSCAN2 = $(patsubst $(OUTDIR)/%varscan.gz,$(OUTSOMATIC)/%varscan2.somatic.vcf, $(filter $(OUTDIR)/%varscan.gz, $(OUTFILES)))
```

and modify the rules to allow Make to determine which intermediates to build:

```
all: $(OUTVARDICT) $(OUTMUTEC2) $(OUTVARSCAN2)

$(OUTDIR)/%.gz: %.vcf $(OUTDIR)
    bgzip -c $<  > $@

$(OUTDIR):
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@

$(OUTSOMATIC):
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@

$(OUTSOMATIC)/%.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%vardict.gz $(OUTSOMATIC)
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS -i 'INFO/STATUS ~ ".*Somatic"' $<  > $@

$(OUTSOMATIC)/%mutect2.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%mutect2_all.gz $(OUTSOMATIC)
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS $<  > $@

$(OUTSOMATIC)/%varscan2.somatic.vcf: $(OUTDIR)/%varscan.gz $(OUTSOMATIC)
    $(BCFTOOLS)  view  -f PASS -i 'SS="2"' $<  > $@
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the new error; when I run with `415_tumor...verdict.vcf`, it produces `SOMATIC/./415_tumor....somatic.vcf` in one pass. And I notice that in your new output, the last command (`bcftools ...`) does not mention the input file or the output file. And that your new makefile builds `SOMATIC/` but builds no vcf file in it. Could you put `$(info list is $(OUTVARDICT))` in your makefile (just above the `all:` rule) and tell me what appears in the output?

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience!!   If I insert that code as you can see here [https://pastebin.com/yxqpMRqG] Now seems run all.. What is the meaning of  that comand? [https://pastebin.com/NZCa4jD6]

Comment: @user3354898: those pages have been removed from pastebin (which is a good example of why we usually dislike such links). Can you tell me the output line "list is ..."?

Comment: Sorry about that!! `list is SOMATIC/./415_tumor_416_normal_merge.vardict.somatic.vcf ` Where I can insert all the script for show you.. in the comment?

Comment: Actually, could you try pastebin again? It might be the best way in this case. If so, give me the full makefile you're using, then run `make clean`, then `make`, and give me the full output of both.